# C compiler cannot create executables on android through termux

Tags: android, linux, bash, sh, termux

I am trying to start verium mining through termux. i have mostly installed the dependencies attached to mine through terminal, but a few of them cannot be downloaded here is the command of the packages which are needed to install before the miner to run.

```
sudo apt-get install git make automake autoconf pkg-config
libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev buildessential
```

one way or other way they are installed and some of them which cannot be installed i installed alternate packages for them.

This is the error which i get when i try to ./build.sh.

```
$ ./build.sh

make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

clean

checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi

checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi

checking target system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi

checking for a BSD-compatible install... 
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/install -c

checking whether build environment is sane... yes

checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mkdir -p

checking for gawk... gawk

checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes

checking whether make supports nested variables... yes

checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for style of include used by make... GNU

checking for gcc... gcc

checking whether the C compiler works... no

configure: error: in `/storage/veriumMiner':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

strip: 'cpuminer': No such file

$ gcc -v

clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)

Target: armv7a--linux-android

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin
```

Here is the config file.

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2386: checking build system type
configure:2400: result: armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
configure:2420: checking host system type
configure:2433: result: armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
configure:2453: checking target system type
configure:2466: result: armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
configure:2514: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2582: result: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/install -c
configure:2593: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2648: result: yes
configure:2799: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2838: result: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2845: checking for gawk
configure:2861: found /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/gawk
configure:2872: result: gawk
configure:2883: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2905: result: yes
configure:2934: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2951: result: yes
configure:3079: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3088: result: no
configure:3114: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3142: result: GNU
configure:3213: checking for gcc
configure:3229: found /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/gcc
configure:3240: result: gcc
configure:3469: checking for C compiler version
configure:3478: gcc --version >&5
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: armv7a--linux-android
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin
configure:3489: $? = 0
configure:3478: gcc -v >&5
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: armv7a--linux-android
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin
configure:3489: $? = 0
configure:3478: gcc -V >&5
clang-5.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-5.0: error: no input files
configure:3489: $? = 1
configure:3478: gcc -qversion >&5
clang-5.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-5.0: error: no input files
configure:3489: $? = 1
configure:3509: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3531: gcc -O2  -Ofast -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ftree-loop-if-convert-stores -DUSE_ASM -pg   conftest.c  >&5
clang-5.0: error: unknown argument: '-ftree-loop-if-convert-stores'
clang-5.0: warning: optimization flag '-fuse-linker-plugin' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
configure:3535: $? = 1
configure:3573: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "cpuminer-multi"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "cpuminer-multi"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.3-dev"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "cpuminer-multi 1.3-dev"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "cpuminer-multi"
| #define VERSION "1.3-dev"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3578: error: in `/storage/veriumMiner':
configure:3580: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```